# ADONISJS: validate some data outside the HTTP request in

Tags: adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

### This is my validator class

```
 import { schema, rules } from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/Validator";
    import { HttpContextContract } from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext";
    
    export default class CreateUserValidator {
      constructor(protected ctx: HttpContextContract) {}
    
      schema = schema.create({
        lat: schema.string({}, [
          rules.regex(/^[-]?(([0-8]?[0-9])\.(\d+))|(90(\.0+)?)$/),
        ]),
    
        lng: schema.string({}, [
          rules.regex(/^[-]?((((1[0-7][0-9])|([0-9]?[0-9]))\.(\d+))|180(\.0+)?)$/),
        ]),
        radius: schema.number(),
        distance: schema.number(),
      });
    
      public messages = {};
    }
```

### This is my controller

```
import { validator } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Validator'
import CreateUser from 'App/Validators/CreateUserValidator'

public async station({
    request,
    response,
  }: HttpContextContract) {
    let inputs: any = await EncyptionManager.decrypt(request.body().inputs);
    inputs = JSON.parse(inputs);

    await validator.validate(
      new CreateUser({
        lat: ainputs.lat,
        long: ainputs.lat,
        radius: ainputs.radius,
        distance: ainputs.distance,
      })
    );
    
    console.log(inputs)
```

Simply, I want to validate lat, long, radius, and distance using the validator classes outside of the HTTP request.

Comment: This should work... I think the issue is that your validator class has dependecy for ctx in constructor. Try removing it.

Comment: [@hlozancic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2039846/hlozancic) Thanks men sorted same i am sending data and my validator expecting `ctx`, Once again thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coz validator constructor is asking for `ctx` and we are passing data
We have to update the validator constructor and remove the dependency on `ctx` and accept data

Now my Validator accept the data

```
import { schema, rules } from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/Validator";
    import { HttpContextContract } from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext";
    
    export default class CreateUserValidator {
      constructor() {}
    
      schema = schema.create({
        lat: schema.string({}, [
          rules.regex(/^[-]?(([0-8]?[0-9])\.(\d+))|(90(\.0+)?)$/),
        ]),
    
        lng: schema.string({}, [
          rules.regex(/^[-]?((((1[0-7][0-9])|([0-9]?[0-9]))\.(\d+))|180(\.0+)?)$/),
        ]),
        radius: schema.number(),
        distance: schema.number(),
      });
    
      public messages = {};
    }
```

Comment: How can I have a single validator class to handle cases where there may or may not be ctx?